# serverless - setting injections \ compliance

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

Is there any solution to “enforce compliance” in serverless or to inject certain configuration on deployment?

we have quite a few repositories\services maintained by different developers and teams. We are now considering making some cross-organizational configuration changes, such as changing the deployment-bucket (used the default until now), or disabling lambda versioning.

the issue is that these changes must be the same across all repositories and serverless.yaml files, so we would like to ensure that each maintainer is using the correct settings.

All of our deployments are triggered via a jenkins pipeline (that runs sls deploy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a plugin called `safeguards-plugin` that might be useful for you: https://github.com/serverless/safeguards-plugin